# UTF8 encoded XHTML content in JSP

Tags: jsp, xhtml

I am trying to display XHTML content in a JSP page. The encoding is UTF8. The jsp page calls a method in a java class and the method returns the xhtml content. Basically this is what I have in my jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0 plus SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f.dtd">
<% response.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml"); %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<% response.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml"); %>
<%=myJavaClass.getXHTML()%>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that some characters show up as QuestionMarks (?).
However, if the java class (myJavaClass) writes the same content to a file, all characters are displayed correctly when I open up the file and view it in a text editor. Tomcat's console also shows the xhtml content with all correct characters, only in the browser I am seeing question marks.

Can anyone think of any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

There are lot of factors which can play a role. In your specific case you're using the old fashioned *scriptlets* to write the XML string to the response. The `<%= foo %>` implicitly calls `response.getWriter().write(foo)`. You need to set the character encoding of the response writer as well by adding the following to **top** of your JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This will set the response encoding to `UTF-8` by implicitly calling `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` **and** it will also add the appropriate response header if not done yet.

All factors which you really need to take into consideration are:

1. Request encoding. For GET requests this needs to be set in appserver's configuration. For POST requests you need to use `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()`.
2. Response encoding. This is already answered here.
3. Database encoding. Specify the encoding during SQL `CREATE`.

For more background information and an detailed overview of all solutions you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) useful.

That said, the lines `<% response.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml"); %>` are completely superfluous if you already have set the `<meta http-equiv="content-type">` in HTML head. Get rid of them and if possible also of the scriptlets. Just use EL:

```
${someBean.somePropertyReturningXmlString}
```