# understanding a practical use for serialization

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

Here is what i understand about serialization:

It lets you take your object and turn it into a stream of bytes so you can save it to a flat file for later use.

I would like to know what what benefit this would serve and why would anyone want to do this.

Comment: I'd believe you have already read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232759/what-is-the-purpose-of-serialization-in-java

Comment: Save data, for games, or any other application with persistent data

Comment: You could spin the question and ask why would anyone **not** want to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very general question - you would serialize an object into bytes for any number of reasons.

- Transfer an object across the internet to another program
- Save an object to a database or file system so you can restore your programs state at a later date or time
- Save an object for the sake of undo/redo within your program

There are many other reasons as well, of course, but you can get the idea from these! I recommend searching online to see if serialization is useful for your application.