# Why while using Spring Boot I need entities to be serializable?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Simple Spring Boot entity CRUD operations work and do not implement the `serializable` interface. Almost every example and tutorial is not doing this and still these examples work well. But the [official simple code samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-hibernate52/src/main/java/sample/hibernate52/domain/Hotel.java) use it.

Why is this interface needed and what is the simplest exemplary use case when implementing `serializable` interface is required?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of Serialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232759/what-is-the-purpose-of-serialization-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to. But looking at the JPA JSR-220 spec there are cases you need to. From the spec:

`If an entity instance is to be passed by value as a detached object (e.g., through a remote interface), the entity class must implement the Serializable interface.`

So if you are passing your object via RMI then you will need to implement Serializable. I can also imagine that Serializable might be needed if you are putting your Entities inside the Session which might be serialized to disk on shutdown of the server.